# Jquery with Eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse

I've the below code made in Dreamweaver CC.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.datepicker.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="Datepicker1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $( "#Datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val; 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i run this is Dreamweaver live view/in a browser, it is working fine.

Now i have a similar file to be created in eclipse project.
I've created a file and pasted the same code even there, and when i run it, there is no datepicker UI show here, also i tried to save and run the file i created in eclipse, but still there is no UI in browser.

please let me know where i went wrong and how can i fix it.

Thanks

Comment: You should check that your path to your js-files are correct, since you copy and pasted are the files still located in a folder jQueryAssets/ relative to the index.html(I assume)-file?

Comment: You should right check on the webpage and choose "Inspect Element" to check whether you miss any JS files. Or add some `console.log` to your JS script to check whether any errors.

Comment: Thanks guys, there was some problem with my libraries finally i took `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">` and it is working fine. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score -1):

i dont know your folder structure. so lets say your file name is index.htm and you are able to view your file in localhost as

http://yourHostMachine.com:80/test/index.htm

now replace the index.htm with jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
http://yourHostMachine.com:80/test/jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js , so if youare not able to see the js file then your path is wrong.

it will be better if you let us know the folder structure of your project :)

thanks